# How to open URL in RecyclerView from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Two buttons Visit and Share have been added with minor modifications. By clicking Visit Button you can visit the corresponding website and a share button is used for sharing data to other applications such as WhatsApp, Gmail..etc. Two buttons Visit and Share have been added with minor modifications. By clicking Visit Button you can visit the corresponding website and a share button is used for sharing data to other applications such as WhatsApp, Gmail..etc. load data from firebase in RecycleView

fetch URL from Firebase and perform an action.

model.java class

```
public class BookModel {
String share;
String visit;


public BookModel() {

}

public BookModel(String share, String visit) {
    this.share = share;
    this.visit = visit;
}

public String getShare() {
    return share;
}

public void setShare(String share) {
    this.share = share;
}

public String getVisit() {
    return visit;
}

public void setVisit(String visit) {
    this.visit = visit;
}
```

RecycleView Adapter  class

```
public class BookAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<BookModel, BookAdapter.ViewHolder> {
Context context;

public BookAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<BookModel> options, Context context) {
    super(options);
    this.context = context;
}

public BookAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<BookModel> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull BookModel model) {

    holder.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        
            // SHARE  INTENT ?
            
            
            
                                        }
                                    });
    holder.visit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( ? ?????));
```

??????

```
        }
    });
}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sample_list, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Button visit;
    Button share;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        visit = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnvisit);
        share = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnshare);
    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To open a URL in Android's web browser from your application, please change the following line of code:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( ? ?????));
```

To:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(model.getVisit()));
```

This will work only if you have a valid URL.