# Android Firebase Onclick Intent how to get URL (on Recyclerview)

Tags: android, firebase, url, android-intent

I'm having trouble to find how can i get URL from my firebase and when a user click on my image get to the url something like this OnClick -> Intent [www.google.pt](http://www.google.pt)

I manage to do this without Firebase, but now i really need a way to do this with Firebase

```
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull PTsModal model)
{
    holder.titulo.setText(model.getTitulo());
    holder.desc.setText(model.getDesc());
    Glide.with(holder.img1.getContext()).load(model.getImgurl())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
            .error(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused)
            .into(holder.img1);
    holder.img1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            //Get url from firebase
        }
    });
}

@NonNull
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.box,parent,false);
    return new myViewHolder(view);
}

class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    ImageView img1;
    TextView titulo, desc;

    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        img1 = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagem_box);
        titulo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_titulo);
        desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_desc);

    }
}
```

my last code was something like this, but it will not work

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(Url[holder.getBindingAdapterPosition()]));
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: So what's the question? And what's wrong with the shared code?

Comment: tha tpreviously code in OnClick wont work, and i can't find code on Internet to get the url

Comment: "won't work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly didn't work?

Comment: i don't know how to write the code for retrive the URL in the method onClick

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, which URL?

Comment: my URL is in the database("Firebase") and when i click the image on the recyclerview i want to intent and go to that URL

Comment: almost like your comment here, but i'm doing with a image instead a button
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68859969/how-to-open-url-in-recyclerview-from-firebase

Comment: In that case, that's almost the exact same thing. Give it a try and show the result.

Comment: Non-static method 'getUrl()' cannot be referenced from a static context